# Scheduled tasks in foreground service not running as per schedule when android app goes into background

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, background-service, foreground-service

I have a react native app which makes a call to a native android module I have written. This native module starts a service in the foreground showing a notification to the user. I have done this because I want my service to run even when the app goes to the background or the screen display is turned off on the phone. Within my service, I am scheduling 2 tasks using the `ScheduledExecutorService`. Below is my code from the `onStartCommand` in my Service class.

The "runScanTask" is scheduled to start at 0 seconds and run every 13 secs after that. The "stopScanTask" is scheduled to start after 8 seconds and run every 13 secs after that. This works perfectly when my screen display is on. However, when I turn off my display, the jobs either stop running altogether or run at intervals which are completely random. Is there a way to get them to work correctly even when the display is turned off?

```
final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

ScheduledFuture<?> startScanFuture = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runScanTask, 0, 13, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
ScheduledFuture<?> stopScanFuture = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(stopScanTask, 8, 13, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Runnable stopScanTask = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      Log.d("main", "STOP BLE SCAN");
   }
};

Runnable runScanTask = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      Log.d("main", "RUN BLE SCAN");
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When your screen is off, your device enters Doze mode as along as the CPU is not doing anything. Do one of the following solutions:

1- Acquire a partial wake lock on your service's onCreate, but it's bad to the battery.

2- Use AlarmManager's [setAndAllowWhileIdle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%2520long,%2520android.app.PendingIntent)) or [setExactAndAllowWhileIdle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%2520long,%2520android.app.PendingIntent)) . (minimum period between tasks 9 minutes when deep doze is active)

3- [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) (minimum period between tasks 15 minutes)

4- [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler) (minimum period between tasks 15 minutes)

5- [Android-Job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) library.

See this [article](https://wangjingke.com/2016/09/23/Multiple-ways-to-schedule-repeated-tasks-in-android) describes the dilemma you are facing.